# Estou com problema com a instalação do Bower, como resolvo?

Tags: front-end, grunt, yeoman, bower

eu estou tendo problema com a instalação do bower, eu já tinha instalado, inclusive trabalhei em alguns projetos utilizando o "yo + grunt + bower" no entanto, hoje quando fui criar um novo projeto obtive um problema na execução do bower, quando eu executo o comando pra instalar novamente dá erro abaixo segue o erro:

```
Mac-mini:jornalmn alexandesigner$ sudo npm install -g bower
Password:
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/lodash.debounce/node_modules/lodash.now/node_modules/lodash._isnative/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/lodash.debounce/node_modules/lodash.now/node_modules/lodash._isnative/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/lodash.debounce/node_modules/lodash.now/node_modules/lodash._isnative/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/request/tests/test-proxy.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/request/tests/test-proxy.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/through/test'
npm ERR! error rolling back  insight@0.3.1 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/through/test']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/through/test' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/collection'
File exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/collection
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/collection
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/collection/map.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chown '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/handlebars/dist/amd/handlebars/base.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/handlebars/dist/amd/handlebars/base.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/handlebars/dist/amd/handlebars/base.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chown
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/test/extglob-ending-with-state-char.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/test/extglob-ending-with-state-char.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/test/extglob-ending-with-state-char.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/redeyed/test'
npm ERR! error rolling back  bower@1.3.8 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/redeyed/test']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/redeyed/test' }
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: /Users/alexandesigner/.npm/lodash._objecttypes/2.4.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! file /Users/alexandesigner/.npm/lodash._objecttypes/2.4.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/mkdirp/test/return_sync.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/mkdirp/test/return_sync.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chown '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/timers-ext/valid-timeout.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/timers-ext/valid-timeout.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/timers-ext/valid-timeout.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chown
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/d/auto-bind.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/d/auto-bind.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/d/auto-bind.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/README.markdown'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/README.markdown
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/README.markdown
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/minimist/index.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/minimist/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/minimist/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at process.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at process.on.process.addListener (node.js:773:26)
    at spinner (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/char-spinner/spin.js:35:13)
    at Object.npm.spinner.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:172:25)
    at Object.commandCache.(anonymous function) (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:202:19)
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:886:18)
    at X (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:916:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:16:22
    at fs.js:949:21
    at OpenReq.Req.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:144:5)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/uuid/benchmark/bench.gnu'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/uuid/benchmark/bench.gnu
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/uuid/benchmark/bench.gnu
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/asn1/lib/ber/writer.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/asn1/lib/ber/writer.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/asn1/lib/ber/writer.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/server.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/server.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/server.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chown '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/inherits'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/inherits
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/inherits
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chown
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/ctype/ctio.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/ctype/ctio.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/ctype/ctio.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/pubsuffix.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/pubsuffix.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/pubsuffix.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alexandesigner/Documents/projects/jornalmn/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Vocês poderiam me ajudar? estou errando em algo? desde já agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Tente `sudo npm uninstall bower` antes.